# Convert '9999-12-31 00:00:00' to 'dd/mm/yyyy' in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe containing the column 'Date' with value as '9999-12-31 00:00:00'. I need to convert it to 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

```
import pandas as pd
data = (['9999-12-31 00:00:00'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date'])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you get any errors? Have you consulted the documentation?

Comment: I'm getting the error: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00 @Exelian

Comment: that is because `pandas` cannot handle such a high year as `datetime` dtype, check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.max.html#pandas-timestamp-max).

Answer (score 1):

Use [daily periods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans) by custom function with remove times by `split` and change format by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.strftime.html):

```
df['Date'] = (df['Date'].str.split()
                        .str[0]
                        .apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x, freq='D'))
                        .dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
print (df)
         Date
0  31/12/9999
```